# Mocha cannot compile Typescript code on Windows

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

For my nodejs module I wrote a few unit tests using Mocha and Chai. They run fine on macOS, but fail to compile on Windows, with this compiler error:

```
D:\projects\antlr4-graps>npm test

> antlr4-graps@1.2.0 test D:\projects\antlr4-graps
> mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register,tsx:ts-node/register


D:\projects\antlr4-graps\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:312
          throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
                ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
test\test.ts (17,1): Cannot find name 'describe'. (2304)
```

The code that fails to compile is:

```
describe('antlr4-graps', function () {
```

which is totally valid code ([the full version of that file is on Github](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr-graps/blob/master/test/test.ts)). I double checked that mocha and chai are installed as local node modules, including their TS equivalents (@type/chai and @type/mocha).

How can I fix the compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import Mocha in your test file. I've reproduced a project with the description you gave of what you have installed and here I just need to add:

```
import "mocha";
```

at the start of a test file so that `describe` and its siblings become defined in the global space.

Comment: Excellent. That was the missing piece (as said it runs without that import on macOS). Interesting is that mocha runs my tests twice in a run on one invocation. But maybe this is the result of the errors it reports currently. In sum, the behavior is quite different compared to macOS, but the differences should be possible to solve. Thanks.

Comment: I just saw the tests run fine in vscode now, only running them from command line gives me the errors. Probably due to different tsc versions (I have VS 2013 and VS 2015 installed on that box as well).